How can I revive a 3 year old Meyer Lemon that never grows?
So this little Meyer is at least 3 years old. It was started in a sunny location, good soil, drainage, kept leaves and had tiny fruit, but never grew or developed. Moved to another location, got worse. Moved to this location in the yard a few months ago. Lost all the leaves, but a couple tiny fruit stayed on. Branches are green, and it does have a tiny new growth on one branch. That's compost we just put on it yesterday. Location gets full sun most of the day, but we are in a coastal area with a lot of Marine layer in the AM.
Should we just start over with a new tree?

...stop moving it and subjecting it to transplant shock?!¿!

Okay - it's been there for about 3 months unmolested - so keeping it as is. How long can it take for recovery?
